# balance -= 10, but subtracts 20?

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a method in my class that charges a fee. The method is this:

```
  public double chargeFee()
  {
    balance -= 10;
    return balance;
  }
```

However, it subtracts 20. I've tried recompiling it but I can't find what is causing the issue.

Complete code:

```
public class ManageAccounts
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     Account acct1, acct2; 


    //create account1 for Sally with $1000
    acct1 = new Account(1000, "Sally", 1111);
    acct2 = new Account(500, "Joe", 2222);//create account2 for Joe with $500

    System.out.println("Depositing $100 into Account 2222...");
    acct2.deposit(100.00);//deposit $100 to Joe's account
    System.out.println("New Balance for Account 2222: $" + acct2.getBalance());//print Joe's new balance (use getBalance())
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Withdrawing $50 from Account 1111...");
    acct1.withdraw(50);//withdraw $50 from Sally's account

    System.out.println("New Balance for Account 1111: $" + acct1.getBalance());//print Sally's new balance (use getBalance())
    System.out.println();
    acct1.chargeFee();
    acct2.chargeFee();//charge fees to both accounts
    System.out.println("Charging usage Fees...");
    System.out.println("Account balance after fees:");
    System.out.println("Account 1111: $" + acct1.chargeFee());
    System.out.println("Account 2222: $" + acct2.chargeFee());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Changing name on Account 2222...");
    acct2.changeName("Joseph");//change the name on Joe's account to Joseph
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Printing account summaries...");
    System.out.println(acct1.toString());
    System.out.println(acct2.toString());//print summary for both accounts

    }
}



import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Account
{
  private double balance;
  private String name;
  private long acctNum;
    NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
  //----------------------------------------------
  //Constructor -- initializes balance, owner, and account number
  //----------------------------------------------
  public Account(double initBal, String owner, long number)
  {
    balance = initBal;
    name = owner;
    acctNum = number;
  }

  //----------------------------------------------
  // Checks to see if balance is sufficient for withdrawal.
  // If so, decrements balance by amount; if not, prints message.
  //----------------------------------------------
  public void withdraw(double amount)
  {
    if (balance >= amount)
       balance -= amount;
    else
       System.out.println("Insufficient funds");
  }

  //----------------------------------------------
  // Adds deposit amount to balance.
  //----------------------------------------------
  public void deposit(double amount)
  {
    balance += amount;
  }

  //----------------------------------------------
  // Returns balance.
  //----------------------------------------------
  public double getBalance()
  {
    return balance;
  }


  //----------------------------------------------
  // Returns a string containing the name, account number, and balance.
  //----------------------------------------------
  public String toString()
  {
    return ("Name: " + name + "\tAccount Number: " + acctNum + "\tBalance: " + money.format(balance));
  }

  //----------------------------------------------
  // Deducts $10 service fee
  //----------------------------------------------
  public double chargeFee()
  {
    balance -= 10;
     return balance;
  }

  //----------------------------------------------
  // Changes the name on the account 
  //----------------------------------------------
  public void changeName(String newName)                          
  {
    name = newName;
  }

}
```

Some sample output:

```
Depositing $100 into Account 2222...
New Balance for Account 2222: $600.0

Withdrawing $50 from Account 1111...
New Balance for Account 1111: $950.0

Charging usage Fees...

Account balance after fees:

Account 1111: $930.0
Account 2222: $580.0

Changing name on Account 2222...

Printing account summaries...
Name: Sally Account Number: 1111    Balance: $930.00
Name: Joseph    Account Number: 2222    Balance: $580.00
```

Comment: You need to call that method only *once*!

Comment: what is your problem exactly????

Comment: +1 for posting code and clear problem description.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I second your notion. +1 from me too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You call `chargeFee` twice on both accounts, once when you charge the actual fee, and again when you print the results.

For future reference, there's a guideline called ["Seperate command and query"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation), or CQS. You might want to read up on it. To put your situation in its light:

- You are using the `chargeFee` as a query ( ie, you return the balance )
- and you use `chargeFee` as a command,  deducting money.

Change `chargeFee` to return a `void` (or `this` if you want method chaining),  and you won't accidently use it as a query.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation

Comment: I would say you should return `this` in this case. Do yo agree?

Comment: Yeah, I had to change it from void to double for the assignment. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

It deducts 2 fees for each account.

```
acct1.chargeFee();
acct2.chargeFee();//charge fees to both accounts
System.out.println("Charging usage Fees...");
System.out.println("Account balance after fees:");
System.out.println("Account 1111: $" + acct1.chargeFee());
System.out.println("Account 2222: $" + acct2.chargeFee());
```

Arguably, `chargeFee()` should not return a balance, but be `void` like `deposit()` or `withdraw()`.  Also note that financial matters are typically dealt with as `int` rather than `double` numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println("New Balance for Account 1111: $" + acct1.getBalance());//print Sally's   new balance (use getBalance())
System.out.println();
acct1.chargeFee();------------------------//First time
acct2.chargeFee();//charge fees to both accounts
System.out.println("Charging usage Fees...");
System.out.println("Account balance after fees:");
System.out.println("Account 1111: $" + acct1.chargeFee());------------------------//second time
System.out.println("Account 2222: $" + acct2.chargeFee());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
1) 
acct1.chargeFee();
acct2.chargeFee();//charge fees to both accounts

2)
System.out.println("Account 1111: $" + acct1.chargeFee());
System.out.println("Account 2222: $" + acct2.chargeFee());
```

Notice how you call `chargeFee()` twice. That is what is giving you the messed up result. You only need to call it once, and simply print the balance in each account the second time (Part 2).

```
System.out.println("Account 1111: $" + Account 1111's balance);
System.out.println("Account 2222: $" + Account 2222's balance);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You already have several correct answers pointing out the problem in your program. This is not really an answer, but an extended comment on how you could have found this problem yourself.

Given a theory a theory that the method chargeFee was subtracting 20, the next step is to add breakpoints or printouts to check what it really does.:

```
public double chargeFee() {
  System.out.println("Before subtract: " + balance + " Account: " + acctNum);
  balance -= 10;
  System.out.println("After subtract: " + balance + " Account: " + acctNum);
  return balance;
}
```

The output from the program with the additional printouts makes it obvious that each call to chargeFee subtracts only 10, but that it is called twice for each account.

Comment: Or for a more comprehensive treatment of debugging, see [Debug Strategy](http://home.earthlink.net/~patricia_shanahan/debug/).  The debugger of an IDE can help, but it is only one part of the process described in that document.

Comment: I feel a little bit embarrassed to keep pushing my own web pages. Please note that I am trying to get links changed to www.patriciashanahan.com/debug/

Comment: *"I feel a little bit embarrassed to keep pushing my own web pages."*  I see no reason you should be shy about giving valuable information.  I'm not (when it comes to my site, or yours).  As far as the link goes: my apologies, I was trusting a certain search engine.  Try instead http://www.patriciashanahan.com/debug/ (which, if it is shown enough times as a link, should eventually supplant the older one).  Another thing might help is to have the old pages auto-redirect to the new domain, since then the users are less likely to book-mark (or repeat) the old URL.